# Access wild card subdomains on local server?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I run a local web server which handles all sub domain traffic for a domain. The domain is on a shared host (HostMonster) I use their DNS manager to send wildcard subdomain traffic to my IP which is dynamic. I know I can use Dynamic DNS to keep DNS working but my ISP has been changing my IP pretty often lately.

I only need to be able to access my subdomains for developing locally. What should I enter into my windows hosts file so I can access zeta.example.com which has a local IP of 192.168.2.14 locally and not have to worry about updating my IP in hostmonster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a local subdomain alias into my nginx server file that matched the entry in my windows hosts file.